# HTML/CSS - Possible way to scale image to fit a certain dimension while maintaining the its aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way that I can use just HMTL and CSS to force an image to resize to fit a fixed dimension while maintaining its aspect ratio (without stretching/shrinking)?

Consider my required dimension to be a 64x64 pixel square, and the following cases for images I want to fit within this dimension:

1. A 64x64 pixel image
2. An image 96 pixels wide and 135 pixels high
3. An image 135 pixels high and 96 pixels wide

I've been able to figure out a way to solve either 1 & 2 or 1 & 3 by explicitly declaring the image's `height="64px"` and `width="64px"` respectively, but one does not work for both, and declaring both causes the image to stretch or shrink.

Is there a way to solve this problem only using HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use max-width and max-height instead. don't set width/height in css.

```
style="max-width: 64px; max-height: 64px;"
```

Comment: Wow, I honestly thought I had tried that. Thank you for the quick and obviously solution.

Comment: @Wex: `max-width` does not work in IE8, images will show max-width size but they will go on occupying their real width, you can try with an horizontal shape rectangle image and set `max-height:60px; max-width:80px;` Issue explained also here http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/max-width#